# How to export and import a store of Vuex in a library of vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-cli

I am working on a small project that consists of two parts:

The first one, in which a component (a chatbot) is customized through various forms, using Vue, Vuetify and Vuex. This all built as 'Web Application' with vue-cli.

A second one, in which you would only have that component that was previously custom built as 'Library' with vue-cli.

My big problem is how you can export the Vuex store from one project to another using a text file. I have tried to do JSON.stringfy () but it is not possible because the Vuex store object has functions and these are not serializable.

The two projects use the same store with the same data.

Attached code to better understand the problem:

Library code:

```
<html>
<head>
[...]
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./lib_chatbot_beta.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="app">
  <chatbot></chatbot>
</div>

</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuex@3.x/dist/vuex.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<script src="./lib_chatbot_beta.umd.js"></script>
<script>
  new Vue({
    // ADD STORE HERE :(
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    components: {
      chatbot: lib_chatbot_beta
    }
  }).$mount('#app')
</script>

</html>
```

Code of how Vuex is imported in the first project (Web Application):
**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'
import store from './store'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

export let vm = new Vue({
  vuetify,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

The vuex files are organized by modules as follows:

```
store
├── index.js
└── modules
    ├── data_api.js
    ├── data_arrow.js
    ├── data_avatar.js
    ├── data_body.js
    ├── data_borderradius.js
    ├── [...]
    [...]
```

You could use the variable 'this.$score' in the web application and by looping the variables and objects it contains and converting them to strings to write them to a file. That file would be read by the library and would create a Vuex instance from it. But be very complicated and laborious.

Comment: Continuing with the hard way of doing it, I'm going to use an AJAX request to read Vuex getters, mutations, and actions and loop through 'this. $.store.state' and then put it all together in a JS file in the library. Unfortunately I don't know how to get the function code from 'this.$.score'